# Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5

Tags: java, javascript, spring, swing, maven

Hi Please help me to resolve this below issue I am new to java, I having POM.xml in my project  which showing below error even after I am done the below mentioned steps.

Steps I tried from my side is

1. Deleted all cache file from maven repository
2. Updated project via Maven, still I am not able to resolve this issue

**Error message is like**

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-    compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
```

**My POM.xml is**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>csp</groupId>
        <artifactId>CustomerFileTransfer</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>CustomerFileTransferApp</name>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Please let me know what am missing to do..

Comment: Which maven version do you use? Have you run on command line? Based on the message you are trying to run maven from Eclipse. Better is to run first on command line and see if everything is working and afterwards going into Eclipse.